# Ubuntu 16.4 LTS freezes when running as a virtual machine under ESXi 6.5

Tags: vmware

Last night I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.4 (desktop) on ESXi 6.5, and within a minute or two it freezes. I have 2GB of memory assigned to it, and 25GB of HDD.

It was a fresh download from ubuntu, all packages etc are upgraded, ...

I found a video on youtube where someone was having the same issue and for him it was caused by the low memory configuration of the video card (initially 4MB). He increased it to 8. I tried, 8, 16, 32 and 64 but in all configs I got a crash within the first few minutes.

The crash usually happens when I use any app on the desktop (including changing settings), and has happened when I SSH'd into the machine to install crashplan (which installs an icon on the desktop).

Does anyone have it running? What config?

The same VMWARE ESXi server runs several instances of ubuntu (headless) and has never had an issue. It also runs windows 10 with no issuesThe same server runs several instances of ubuntu (headless) and has never had an issue and has run a VM of os x in the past as well.

HELP!!!

UPDATE:  THIS IS A KNOWN BUG THAT HAS BEEN FIXED IN 6.5.0 update 1.

I fixed by uploading to synology iSCSI and running

esxcli software vib install -d /vmfs/volumes/SynologyiSCSI/updates/update-from-esxi6.5-6.5_update01.zip

Comment: Can you provide your desktop's specifications? It could be your hardware incompability.

Comment: ESXi is running on a 2012 mac mini server (I7) with 16GB or ram using iSCSI storage running on synology. Client is mac pro workstation with 12GB of memory.  It freezes/ crashes using the web based ESXi browser console (safari- all other VMs run fine) or the vmware fusion remote console

Comment: Try to do a recovery boot, choose root option, and  `cat /var/log/syslog` to look for any messages that may have any hint to this freeze.

Comment: @juanjulio can you explain which issue was fixed in the ESXi 6.5.0 U1 release? we are experiencing VM freezes with Ubuntu 14.04 machines, but I can't figure out which fix on the ESXi 6.5.0 U1 release notes addresses this issue.