# How to prevent Xubuntu 16.04.3 to hang on ESXi 6.5?

Tags: xubuntu, vmware, syslog, esx

I've just installed Xubuntu 16.04.3 on a VMware Vsphere ESXi 6.5 system but at random moments the system hangs for which I can only perform a hard reset to be able to reconnect. I already played with the RAM and video memory but no real change.

This is the configuration of my ESXi 6.5:

[image]

And here an extract from `/var/log/syslog`

[syslog](http://ge.tt/4XlKPnm2)

In ESXI there the following event occurs:

```
The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or reset the virtual machine.
```

I've found the following [KB article](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2000542)

I've installed the `linux-crashdump` [tools](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html) and now I have a vmlinuz file but at the moment I'm stuck at how to analyze it.

Maybe it could also be a bug in ESXI 6.5 as I learn in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/957660/ubuntu-16-4-lts-freezes-when-running-as-a-virtual-machine-under-esxi-6-5).

What could be the cause of the sudden system halts? 
I'll be happy to provide further information through syslogs.

Comment: Cannot see syslog. Post as flat text on a http server. 
Details. Do you run the ESX host? How much free RAM is there?  Do other VM appliances have trouble? In the VM system, what do you see in terminal "dmesg" output before thing dies? Maybe that does not matter. Symptom you describe makes me think the host resources are being strained, if it's RAM is exhausted by other clients, the problem you describe can happen.

Comment: Hi, I changed the host of the file. Hopefully you can download it now. It is our ESX host. I'm doubting any performance issues as the system is fairly new and there are only 3 VM's installed: there are plenty of resources available. Other (Windows) host are not affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem (sort of) by migrating the VM to another ESXI (5.1) in the company and on this server it has not given me any problems so far. Thus, most probably the problem relies in ESXI 6.5.

Comment: I too have the same problem, even posted on VMWare community forum, No reply.

Comment: Highly inconvenient... To add: this week I've installed ubuntu 16.04.4 server edition on the same ESXI and this runs without any problem.